# Spring-XD Curator Connection Timeout

Tags: spring, spring-xd, apache-curator

In Spring-XD the Curator Connection times out:

> WARN ConnectionStateManager-0 curator.ConnectionState - Connection
>   attempt unsuccessful after 63021 (greater than max timeout of 60000).
>   Resetting connection and trying again with a new connection.

Curator tries to re-establish the connection, but fails. Please check the logs below. Has anyone faced similar issue? Please let me know if you know of any ways to resolve the issue or if you know of any workarounds.

Also the default Curator connection time out is 60000. Is there a way to increase it? Does spring-xd expose a property which can be set?

```
2014-12-10 01:24:41,003  WARN ConnectionStateManager-0
server.ContainerRegistrar - >>> disconnected container:
1c8a234d-4b8d-4d65-b374-xxxxe8619 2014-12-10 01:24:41,004  INFO
DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Path cache
event: null, type: CONNECTION_SUSPENDED 2014-12-10 01:24:41,005  INFO
ConnectionStateManager-0 server.ContainerRegistrar - Undeploying
module [ModuleDescriptor@350920b1 moduleName = 'rabbit', moduleLabel =
'rabbit', group = 'xxx-ingestion-2', sourceChannelName = [null],
sinkChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type =
source, parameters = map['vhost' -> 'xxx_virtual_host', 'requeue' ->
'false', 'outputType' -> 'text/plain', 'queues' -> 'xx.xxx.queue',
'addresses' -> 'xxxmq.xx.xxxx.com'], children = list[[empty]]]
2014-12-10 01:24:46,022 ERROR pool-22-thread-1
connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: clean
connection shutdown; protocol method:
method<connection.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
```

```
2014-12-10 01:24:56,007 **ERROR CuratorFramework-0
curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out for connection string
(514.xx.93.xxx:2181,504.58.xxx.xx:2181) and timeout (15000) / elapsed**
(15004) org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException:
KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:198)
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88)
    at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:793)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$400(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:58)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 2014-12-10 01:24:56,161
ERROR main-EventThread curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out
for connection string (514.xx.93.xxx:2181,504.58.xxx.xx:2181) and
timeout (15000) / elapsed (15159)
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode =
ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:198)
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88)
    at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl$4.call(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:291)
    at org.apache.curator.RetryLoop.callWithRetry(RetryLoop.java:107)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.pathInForeground(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:279)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.GetDataBuilderImpl.forPath(GetDataBuilderImpl.java:41)
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.ContainerRegistrar$StreamModuleWatcher.process(ContainerRegistrar.java:744)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.NamespaceWatcher.process(NamespaceWatcher.java:67)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.processEvent(ClientCnxn.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:498)


2014-12-10 01:25:03,014 ERROR CuratorFramework-0 imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - **Background retry gave up**
org.apache.curator.CuratorConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode =
ConnectionLoss
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.checkTimeouts(ConnectionState.java:198)
    at org.apache.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:88)
    at org.apache.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.performBackgroundOperation(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:793)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$400(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:58)
    at org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$4.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this reproducible? Are you running in clustered or single node mode?

The Curator connection timeout (in milliseconds) can be set via system property `curator-default-connection-timeout`.

Comment: Yes its  reproducible, I am running in clustered  mode.

Comment: Apologies; I didn't see your response until now. Is this still an issue? I recommend running the latest Spring XD as it contains some fixes regarding connectivity to ZooKeeper.